# handling height of the image which is set as a background using :before pseudo element using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have created one navigation bar using bootstrap and jquery. In my navigation   bar their is one background image, which is left to the logo.I am facing problem during mobile view,the problem is:In mobile,on click of hamburger icon,when navigation menu get collapse and expand,that same time i need to increase and decrease height of that background image which is left to the logo.

below is link jsfiddle link:https://jsfiddle.net/gbhopale/utb6adyp/3/

HTML Code:

```
   <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#mydiv">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"> <img src="../images/logo_mobile_2x.png" class="img-responsive logo-img" alt="Image"> </a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="mydiv">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav font-bold">
        <li><a href="#">Register</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown provider-menu">
          <a href="#" id="accuntid" class="dropbtn">Account<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></i></a>
          <div class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="update-registered-providers.html">Update Provider Information</a>
            <a href="#">Register New Provider</a>
            <a href="#">Reset Password</a>
            <a href="#">Update Account Information</a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-off"></span> Logoff</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```